# Tensorflow.js, function predict is not defined

Tags: javascript, json, tensorflow, google-chrome-extension, tensorflow.js

I am developing a chrome extension, where I use my trained keras model, downloading it by the library `tensorflow.js`. 
As I can see from DevTools, model is loaded fine, but I can't use it (can't use function `predict()`).

`background.js`

```
const start = async function() {
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/myAcc/myRep/master/model.json');
return model;
}

const model = start();

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function predict(data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(model.predict(data));
    var prediction = model.predict(data);
    if (prediction[0] == 1){
        alert("Yes");
    }
    else {
        alert("No");
    }
}
                                  );
```

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "0.1",

  "background": {
        "scripts": ["tf.min.js", "background.js"]
   },
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js","content.js"]
      }
   ],
   "permissions":  ["https://*/"]
}
```

I get an error in `background.js`

Error in event handler: TypeError: model.predict is not a function

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your **async** function `start` doesn't return a model. It returns a Promise which resolves to a model.

You have to wait until this Promise resolve to work with the model. You can do it for example by using `.then()` on the Promise and use the parameter it gets called with.

Comment: Thank you for help ! 
I changed my code, also I noticed that I had one more mistake - didn't use tf.tensor. Now my function looks like:
   `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function predict(data){
        console.log(data);
        model.then(model => {
            var prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor(data));
        });

    }
     );`
where data = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
I had an error: "Error when checking : expected dense_input to have shape [null,16] but got array with shape [16,1].". Could you help me and tell how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I tried to solve it like 
`var prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor(data).reshape([null, 16]));`
but it still doesn't work
**Uncaught (in promise) Error: Size(16) must match the product of shape ,16**

Comment: The solution was (in a case if anybody is interested):
`var prediction = model.predict(tf.tensor(data).reshape([1, 16]));`